# How to build static lib of ecl.dll under Windows with MSVC2010?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ecl

I want to build a program ("exe" or "static lib") using ECL, but under windows. My application must depend on "ecl.dll".

How to modify the MSVC makefile to build ECL statically?

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in the mailing list, ECL's Makefile for Microsoft's compilers currently does not have this option. It simply hasn't been ported from their siblings that run on Unix-type environments. But that does not mean it cannot be done.